# How do i get all the public methods of a model?

Tags: java, gwt

I need get all the gets() of a model in my code.

Ex:

Model.java

```
private int var1;
private int var2;
private int var3;

public getVar1()...
public getVar2()...
public getVar3()...
```

Comment: IMO this needs more clarification? do you want to use `Refelction` or what?

Comment: Although on second thought, is the fact this has a `gwt` label relevant?

Comment: @biziclop Apparently, GWT does not support reflection. So you have to use a work around. So GWT tag is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, maybe?

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
Class objClass = myClass.getClass();
Set<Method> getMethods = new HashSet<Method>();

for (Method method : objClass.getMethods()) {
    if(method.getName().contains("getVar")) {
        getMethods.add(method);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

**above is wrong!** I did not see the GWT tag. Apparently, there is a good API for reflection for GWT, and you may be able to use my code:

http://gwtreflection.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I'm pretty sure GWT doesn't support Reflection on client-side, so this would have to be done server-side.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, you know what, I didn't even see the GWT tag. Will delete in a min.

Comment: Neither have I and I even voted for closing. Pffft.